# How to change maximum and minimum label in ggvis plot

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to create a ggvis plot. I want the maximum value on the y-axis to be 220 and the minimum value to be 0, so I added `values = seq(0,220,20)` in `add_axis()`. But the problem is after I do this the 
the plot looks like the picture below. Does anyone know how do I fix it?

```
df = data.frame(date = c("12/24/2015", "12/25/2015","12/27/2015", "12/29/2015", 
                         "12/26/2015", "12/30/2015"),
                rate = runif(6,50,150),stringsAsFactors=F)

library(ggvis)
df%>%
  ggvis(~date, ~rate)%>%
  layer_lines()%>%
  layer_points()%>%
  add_axis("y", subdivide = 1, values = seq(0,220,20))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the default data limits you can add the appropriate *scale*.  In this case, you will need `scale_numeric` and the `domain` argument.  Once you change the data limits, you can change what the y axis looks like with `add_axis` as in the OP.

```
df %>%
    ggvis(~date, ~rate) %>%
    layer_lines() %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(0, 220)) %>%
    add_axis("y", subdivide = 1)
```

[image]

The ggvis [properties and scales page](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/properties-scales.html) has some examples of this in the "Properties -> scales" section.